# JQuery.Ajax calling WebMethod + event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webmethod

I have an asp.net application, one page is using JQuery.Ajax to call a WebMethod function in aspx code

// Default.aspx.cs

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetCustomersCount()
{
    ...
    dbReader.OnReadAsyncComplete += (_o, _e) => { ... };
    ...
}
```

this function reads data from database (asynchronously) and has an event handler OnReadAsyncComplete.
Now how can I access any client or server UI element (label, textbox - whatever) - to write some value in that UI element?
WebMethod is static, so neither Response object nor UI Elements with runat="server" are not accessible in dbReader.OnReadAsyncComplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do things that way, that's what postback-style code is for. If you're doing AJAX-style programming instead, your client-side code is where you update your page:

```
$.ajax(...).then(function(data) {
    $('#your-label').text(data.someValue);
});
```

Comment: Postback how? WebMethod is static, Response object not available

Comment: If you were doing postback-style programming, you wouldn't use a `WebMethod` at all. I'm just telling you that you'll have to choose one or the other. You can't update the UI in a `WebMethod`.